# Convert a nested separated string to a Object

Tags: java, json, tree, csv

I'm trying to convert a nested dot-separated file like this:

```
AAA, value1, value11
AAA.BBB, value3, value22
AAA.BBB.CCC, value3, value33
AAA.DDD, values44, value44
```

to Object, that would be able to describe as JSON:

```
{
    "name": "AAA",
    "type": "value1",
    "property": "value11",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "BBB",
            "type": "value2",
            "property": "value22",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "CCC",
                    "type": "value3",
                    "property": "value33",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "DDD",
            "type": "value4",
            "property": "value44",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Please advice me, how to implement this case in Java?

I have already tried to do handmade JSON like this, but it's doesn't work for me. I can't properly implement a parent-children structure.

```java
static abstract class Node {
}

static class IntermediateNode extends Node {
    public Map<String, Node> keyValueMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[{");
        sb.append(keyValueMap.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> "\"name\":\"" + entry.getKey() + "\", \"children\"" + ":" + entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        sb.append("}]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public void test(String source) {
    IntermediateNode root = new IntermediateNode();

    String[] lines = source.split("\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        List<String> values = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
        String[] paths = values.get(0).split("\\.");

        IntermediateNode currentNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.length - 1; i++) {
            Node node = currentNode.keyValueMap.get(paths[i]);
            if (node == null) {
                IntermediateNode child = new IntermediateNode();
                currentNode.keyValueMap.put(paths[i].trim(), child);
                currentNode = child;
            } else {
                currentNode = (IntermediateNode) node;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a library like `org.json:json` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more succinct and elegant ways to do this, but this should be pretty robust to errors, missing nodes and unsorted data (see example input below; I assume you can read the file so I'll begin working with a list of strings).

For starters, it's a good idea to use [`org.json`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) or some other library to save reinventing the wheel and dealing with various edge cases during the serialization process. If you're dealing with simple strings as you seem to be, it may be doable, but rolling it yourself should be a last resort.

As for the algorithm, my approach was to tokenize each line and walk backwards through the path, creating `Node` objects for any missing items and keeping them in a hash keyed by path name. Last items in each line's path are leaves and will be assigned the properties for that line, while interior nodes look up and add children from previously-parsed nodes using a hash. This builds a linked n-ary tree structure.

The next step is to find the root (we assert that there is only one root) and run the JSON serializer, starting with leaves and passing serialized objects back up to parents recursively.

Note that `org.JSON` will sort keys but the result is as much in compliance with the JSON spec as your expected output, which guarantees no ordering for object properties.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

class Node {
    String name;
    String type;
    String property;
    ArrayList<Node> children;

    public Node(String name, String type, String property, ArrayList<Node> children) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.property = property;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        JSONArray serializedChildren = new JSONArray();

        for (Node child : children) {
            serializedChildren.put(child.toJSON());
        }

        return new JSONObject()
            .put("name", name)
            .put("type", type)
            .put("property", property)
            .put("children", serializedChildren);
    }
}

public class Main {
    private static void validate(boolean cond, String msg) {
        if (!cond) throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }

    private static void parseLine(HashMap<String, Node> nodes, String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(", ");
        validate(tokens.length == 3, "There must be 3 tokens per line");
        String[] names = tokens[0].split("\\.");
        validate(names.length != 0, "There must be at least one name in the path");

        for (int i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String name = String.join(".", Arrays.copyOfRange(names, 0, i + 1));
            Node node = nodes.get(name);

            if (node == null) {
                nodes.put(name, node = new Node(names[i], null, null, new ArrayList<>()));
            }

            if (i < names.length - 1) {
                Node child = nodes.get(name + "." + names[i+1]);
                validate(child != null, "Child lookup must succeed");

                if (!node.children.contains(child)) {
                    node.children.add(child);
                }
            }
            else {
                node.type = tokens[1];
                node.property = tokens[2];
            }
        }
    }

    public static HashSet<Node> parseNodes(List<String> lines) {
        var nodes = new HashMap<String, Node>();
        lines.forEach((line) -> parseLine(nodes, line));

        for (Node node : nodes.values()) {
            String[] tokens = node.name.split("\\.");
            node.name = tokens[tokens.length-1];
        }

        return new HashSet<Node>(nodes.values());
    }

    public static Node findRoot(HashSet<Node> tree) {
        var candidates = new HashSet<Node>(tree);
        tree.forEach((node) -> candidates.removeAll(node.children));
        validate(candidates.size() == 1, "There must be one root");

        for (Node root : candidates) return root;

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var lines = Arrays.asList(
            "AAA.BBB.CCC, value3, value33",
            "AAA.BBB.CCC.EEE.FFF, value5, value55",
            "AAA.BBB, value3, value22",
            "AAA, value1, value11",
            "AAA.DDD, values44, value44"
        );
        Node root = findRoot(parseNodes(lines));
        System.out.println(root.toJSON().toString(2));
    }
}
```

Compiled and executed with:

```
javac -cp "json-20190722.jar" Main.java && java -cp "json-20190722.jar;." Main
```

Output:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [{
        "children": [{
          "children": [{
            "children": [],
            "name": "FFF",
            "property": "value55",
            "type": "value5"
          }],
          "name": "EEE"
        }],
        "name": "CCC",
        "property": "value33",
        "type": "value3"
      }],
      "name": "BBB",
      "property": "value22",
      "type": "value3"
    },
    {
      "children": [],
      "name": "DDD",
      "property": "value44",
      "type": "values44"
    }
  ],
  "name": "AAA",
  "property": "value11",
  "type": "value1"
}
```

Comment: It's an amazing solution! Thank you for the help!